# Change the button color at Runtime depending on property when VCL Styles are applied

Tags: custom-component, delphi-10.2-tokyo, vcl-styles, skins

I am working with VCL styles in Delphi 10.2.

I have a `MyButtonStyle` property on a custom button component - `TMyButton`, which inherits from `TButton`.

```pascal
type
  MyButtonStyle = ('Default', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Green');
```

Based on the `MyButtonStyle` property values:

When a VCL Style is applied, I want to change the color of `TMyButton` to either: Default (default selected style color), Red, Yellow, or Green.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

I tried using the Bitmap Style Designer in Delphi. But it allows selecting a color only at design-time. How to achieve this at runtime?

Comment: Are you trying to *create* a custom VCL style? If so, why are you not using the [VCL's built-in styling system](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Working_with_VCL_Styles) to apply your style to your button? See [Creating a Style using the Bitmap Style Designer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_a_Style_using_the_Bitmap_Style_Designer) and [Managing a Style](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/VCL_Styles_Overview#Managing_a_Style).

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Remy. Yes, I want to create a custom vcl style(or modify existing vcl styles). I tried using bitmap designer. But in that I can assign any one color value. In my case, When a VCL Style is applied, I want to change the color of TMyButton to either: Default (default selected style color), Red, Yellow, or Green depending on MyButton property MyButtonStyles value programmatically

Comment: A control can have only 1 style applied at a time, and the style dictates the coloring. You would need 4 separate styles, 1 for each color, and then switch between the styles as needed. Note that the VCL supports [per-control styling](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/What%27s_New#VCL_Per_Control_Styling) only in 10.4+. For what you are attempting to do in 10.2, styles is probably not the way to go, you should look at owner-drawing instead. Give the button the `BS_OWNERDRAW` window style, and then handle the `WM_DRAWITEM` message to draw the button however you want.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help @RemyLebeau. Wanted to know whether owner-drawing have any limitations when vcl style is used?

Comment: VCL styling is implemented using owner-drawing and hooks. If you handle `WM_DRAWITEM` manually, you will likely lose styled elements unless you draw them manually as well. If you even want your button to honor the active style, that is.

Comment: @Remylebeau Will lose styled elements of only the button or other components as well? For applying active style to button I think I can set style color by calliing GetStyleColor.

Comment: Only for your button that you are handling drawing messages for.

Comment: ok, thanks alot for the help @RemyLebeau